How to export specific metrics from Dagster to Prometheus?
I am trying to set up monitoring for jobs running in Dagster and want to scrape metrics off of the jobs with Prometheus.
The metrics that I am interested in are:

Whether the jobs running succeed or fail
The duration of time it takes for them to run

I have a basic understanding of how to use Prometheus and have set up a Prometheus Pushgateway. However, I am struggling to correctly configure Dagster to push the job status and duration metrics to Prometheus.
I have created a custom sensor in Dagster to monitor the job status and duration, and I am using the prometheus_client library to define and push metrics. Here's the code I have so far:
from dagster_prometheus import PrometheusResource
from dagster import DagsterRunStatus, RunRequest, op, run_status_sensor, SkipReason
from orchestration.jobs import all_dbt_assets_job

from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, Gauge, push_to_gateway
from dagster import DagsterInstance

# Prometheus configuration
PUSHGATEWAY_URL = "http://localhost:9091"
registry = CollectorRegistry()

# Define Prometheus metrics
run_status_gauge = Gauge('dagster_run_status', 'Status of Dagster runs', ['job_name', 'status'], registry=registry)
run_duration_gauge = Gauge('dagster_run_duration_seconds', 'Duration of Dagster runs in seconds', ['job_name'], registry=registry)

@op
def prometheus_op(prometheus: PrometheusResource):
    push_to_gateway(PUSHGATEWAY_URL, job=str(all_dbt_assets_job), registry=prometheus.registry)

@run_status_sensor(
    run_status=DagsterRunStatus.SUCCESS,
    monitored_jobs=[all_dbt_assets_job],
)
def report_status_sensor(context):
    instance = DagsterInstance.get()

    # Ensure we're not monitoring the status reporting job itself
    if context.dagster_run.job_name == 'status_reporting_job':
        return SkipReason("Don't report status of status_reporting_job")

    # Get the run details
    run = instance.get_run_by_id(context.dagster_run.run_id)
    job_name = run.pipeline_name
    status = 'success' if run.status == DagsterRunStatus.SUCCESS else 'failure'
    duration = (run.end_time - run.start_time).total_seconds() if run.end_time and run.start_time else 0

    # Update Prometheus metrics
    run_status_gauge.labels(job_name=job_name, status=status).set(1 if status == 'success' else 0)
    run_duration_gauge.labels(job_name=job_name).set(duration)

    # Push metrics to Prometheus Pushgateway
    push_to_gateway(PUSHGATEWAY_URL, job=job_name, registry=registry)

    run_config = {
        "ops": {
            "status_report": {"config": {"job_name": job_name}}
        }
    }
    return RunRequest(run_key=None, run_config=run_config)


I don't know what's wrong with your code (of anything, you don't specify what seems to be a problem), but you for sure should not put status into label of run_status_gauge. Since Pushgateway doesn't forget "old" metrics, you'll have both series for failus and success (once each of the appear). You should put it into the value only.
